# Asp.net MVC4, Controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class CheckoutController : Controller
{
    string userID;

    public CheckoutController()
    {
        userID = User.Identity.Name;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I run the above code, I get this error,

```
**Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.**
```

In that class, most of method need that userID, so I want to define that value in constructor, how can I solve this problem?

[Edit]

```
public class CheckoutController : Controller
{
    string userID;

    public CheckoutController()
    {
      //None
    }
}
```

This code works fine, no error.

Comment: Are you sure this is the controller that the routing is calling? It looks like you already have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: If so, have you rebuilt your code recently? It may be out of date...

Comment: @Expert as it is out of the box, only parameterless constructors work `public CheckoutController()`, but you would like to make use of `public CheckoutController(int userId)`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted.  Obviously, the problem is somewhere else, or you're working with old code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execution pipeline related values (`Request`, `Response`, and `User`) are binded **ONLY AFTER** the `Controller`'s constructor method.  That is why you can't use `User.Identity` as it is not binded yet. Only after the **Step 3: `IController.Execute()`** is when those contextual values are initialized.

<strike>http://blog.stevensanderson.com/blogfiles/2007/ASPNET-MVC-Pipeline/ASP.NET%20MVC%20Pipeline.jpg</strike>

**Updated Poster:** [link to a newer poster based on @mystere-man's feedback thanks to @SgtPooki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbUBe.png). But I am keeping the older embeddable image in here to make it a bit easier to reference.

[image: ASP.NET MVC Pipeline]

`User.Identity.Name` does not negatively affect the performance as it has already been decrypted from the `FormsAuthentication` cookie by the ASP.NET runtime (*assuming you are using `FormsAuthentication` for your web application*).

So don't bother caching it to a class member variable.

```cs
public class CheckoutController : Controller
{
    public CheckoutController() { /* leave it as is */ }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // just use it like this
        string userName = User.Identity.Name;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, that chart is WAY out of date, I think it was for a Pre-CTP1 of MVC1 and things changed quite a bit afterwards.  There's a much better one referenced here http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/10/08/aspnet-mvc-learning-resource-request-handling-pipeline-poster/

Comment: Thanks go to both of you. Also, I submitted an edit in order to provide a better link. And just in-case: http://i.imgur.com/96jp1eu.png